# Changing an image color profile on frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, color-profile

I'd like to download an image from my API and chose color profile frontend side in order to give different download options (like CMYK/RGB, grayscale...). My frontend is a React TS app.

I know image tweaks are mostly done backend (with libraries like Multer or Sharp), but I'd like to know if somthing exist to do this work directly on the browser. My API is in GO, but I'd rather not have to add code to it, whence the question.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can read and modify files in the frontend.

Comment: Which tool should I use to do that? Is it with vanilla JS?

Comment: Every code in the browser is based on vanilla JS. Every library is only vanilla JS written by other developers. You can e.g. use the [File interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). Asking for recommendations for third-party libraries is off-topic.

Comment: As an alternative you could use webassembly.